# Single expression with .sort() method and slicing on a list

Tags: python, sorting

I want to achieve `min()`, `max()` by using sorting and slicing on list with numbers.
With `sorted()` function, there are elegant solutions:

```
maximum = lambda arr: sorted(arr)[-1]
```

or

```
def maximum(arr): 
    return sorted(arr)[-1]
```

But if I want to achieve elegant solution with more memory efficient `.sort()` method I'm in bottleneck.

Since, `.sort()` is sorting, without creating new list, and thus returns **None**, the only one-liner I did is:

```
def maximum(arr):
    return arr[-1] if arr.sort() == None else "Huston, we found a bug!"
```

This is not very pythonic. Is there a way for single and elegant expression with `.sort()` and slicing?

Comment: Maybe this is just "for fun," but note that sorting a list is O(n*log(n)), while the typical algorithm for finding min and/or max are O(n). Also, using `.sort` will make your `maximum` a destructive operation, which seems like a big disadvantage. Finally, the "Pythonic" way is often to avoid one-liners. :-)

Comment: The pythonic way would be to use the built-in min and max functions. What keeps you from doing that???

Comment: This is from Codewars challenge. There are defined functions named min() and max() and I should use something different, to avoid recursion.

Comment: Don't use `sorted`. Just iterate over the list and find the smallest and largest value. That is the most memory and time efficient solution.

Comment: Also, you seem to be conflating "elegant" with "one-liner", when those are only sometimes correlated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wholeheartedly agree with what J.Doe said, but if you insist on a one-liner, this looks a bit better:

```
def maximum(arr):
    return arr.sort() or arr[-1]
```

Since `.sort()` returns `None` and `None` evaluates to `False` in boolean context, this will always work.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way to accomplish what you desired in one line but it is not pythonic. I interestingly think using `min()` or `max()` is the more pythonic approach. because it is not only faster and more simple and readable.

if you type `import this` in your python interpreter you would see "The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters" and it stated:

> Simple is better than complex.

and

> Readability counts.